# Gradle publish Invalid publication 'maven': artifact file does not exist

Tags: java, gradle

I have a java with gradle (5.2) project and I'm trying to publish it to [myMavenRepo](https://mymavenrepo.com/)

My build.gradle

```
plugins {   
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
}


group = 'com.doe'
version = '1.0.0'

sourceCompatibility = 10
targetCompatibility = 10


repositories {        
     mavenCentral()
     maven { url  MY_MAVEN_REPO_READ_URL }
}

dependencies { ... }


task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url MY_MAVEN_REPO_WRITE_URL
        }
    }

    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            artifact sourceJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I always receive this error:

Invalid publication 'maven': artifact file does not exist: '/build/libs/project-1.0.0.jar'

And the .jar is always created with this name: `project-1.0.0-sources.jar`

So I tried to remove that 'sources' from the name changing classifier to empty:

```
 artifact sourceJar {
                classifier ""
 }
```

But I received this error:

Invalid publication 'maven': multiple artifacts with the identical extension and classifier ('jar', 'null').

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

The Spring Boot plugin replaces the default jar of the project by an executable jar, which is not registered with `components.java`.

Have a look at the [Spring Boot plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#publishing-your-application-maven-publish) on how to publish the executable jar.